# the language you might see in ads for girdles or jockey shorts

Tags: meaning

The meaning of a sentence

The passage comes from The Glamour of Grammar.

> There was one language distinction I found almost impossible to master
>   until I tripped over an alternate terminology: the difference between
>   a restrictive and nonrestrictive relative clause. Restrictive and
>   nonrestrictive sound a little like ***the language you might see in ads
>   for girdles or jockey shorts***.

I don't think I do understand the following part of the last sentence, "***the language you might see in ads for girdles or jockey shorts***."
I mean the implied meaning under the literal surface.

Comment: The literal meaning is what is meant. 'The first (and possibly only) thing most people think of when hearing 'restrictive' / 'nonrestrictive' is tight-fitting clothing.'